# Counting points in elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, computational-complexity

Given an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Z_n$

1. Is it $\#P$ hard to compute $\# E(\mathbb Z_n)$?
2. Is it $PP$-hard to compute $\# E(\mathbb Z_n)\leq\frac n2$?
3. Is it $\oplus P$ hard to compute $\# E(\mathbb Z_n)\bmod 2$?

Comment: Could you define what you call an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking on this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95408/elliptic-curves-over-rings. If not appropriate I can take it down or just use $\mathbb F_q$ since that does not change the nature of the question.

Comment: And even define $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as it's both used for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and for the $n$-adics (projective limit of $\mathbb{Z}/n^k\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I was just think $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. I doubt over infinite sets the problem makes sense.

Comment: Thanks to the Chinese remainder theorem and the known structure of the formal group of elliptic curves, these questions all boil down to calculating group orders for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$. In particular 2 should be easy and 3 is trivial as there is not problem checking if there are $2$-torsion points.

Comment: For $n$ prime we have Schoof's algorithm which is polynomial in the number of bits, so all these problems are in $P$.  For other $n$ the hardest step might be factoring, which is not believed to be polynomial time, but also not expected to be hard for any of these hardness classes.

Comment: For a reference, see the Wikipedia page on "Counting points on elliptic curves" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_points_on_elliptic_curves

Comment: @willsawin Does counting points give factors?

Comment: I'm just saying you could first factor and then count points on each prime. This means counting points can't be #P-hard unless factoring is.

Comment: I understand. I am asking converse question.